# A problem about the connectivity of vertices that must have the same color for any proper minimal $4$-coloring of a graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, problem-solving, coloring, graph-connectivity

Two vertices $u, v$ of a finite graph $G(V, E)$ are said to be *entangled* if for any proper coloring $c:V(G)\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $\chi(G)$ colors we have $c(u) = c(v)$, that is, they must have the same color.

In [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561468/a-problem-about-the-connectivity-of-vertices-that-must-have-the-same-color-for-a) I made a false conjecture about the connectivity of entangled vertices. There I ask if

*"Given a graph $G$ and two entangled vertices $u, v\in V(G)$, is there $w\in V(G)$ (possibly equal to $v$) also entangled with $u$ so that there are $\chi(G)-1$ disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$?"*

It turns out that the conjecture is false for $\chi(G) \ge 5$, as shown by a counter example in that post. I would like to know now if the conjecture is true for the case $\chi(G) = 4$, i.e., if

*"Given a $4$-chromatic graph $G$ and two entangled vertices $u, v\in V(G)$, is there $w\in V(G)$ (possibly equal to $v$) also entangled with $u$ so that there are $3$ disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$?"*

In fact, it was this particular case that inspired me to come up with this conjecture. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: If you consider the complete graph $K_5$ but you remove an edge between $u$ and $v$, then $\chi(G)=4$ (because you can use the same color for $u$ and $v$) the vertices $u$ and $v$ are entangled (because they are linked to the three same vertices) and you have 3 paths going from $u$ to $v$ (one for each of the other vertices). It's just an example, but maybe we can work our way starting from this.

Comment: Does disjoint mean edge disjoint or vertex disjoint?

Comment: "disjoint" mean "vertex disjoint".

Comment: I have thoroughly enjoyed working on this problem. If you intend to work more on it or publish anything, I would be keen to collaborate.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez, I'm not sure about publishing anything. I just realized that the result I needed is slightly different from what I posted here. I intend to continue working on it, and if I get any interesting results, I will contact you again!

Comment: @Arjuna196 Awesome! I look forward to it if you do ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is true for $\chi(G) = 4$.

I have posted [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354458/a-problem-about-the-connectivity-of-vertices-that-must-have-the-same-color-for-a) on math overflow, which feels like a more appropriate place for the rather involved proof.